# Data points in hierarchial clustering

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

In Hierarchy Clustering(Single Link or Complete Link), is it possible for a point to be closer to points in other clusters than to every point in its own cluster?

I understand that, in single linkage, the distance between two clusters is the minimum distance between the two groups, i.e. the distance between the data points closest to the other cluster is taken as the distance between the two clusters. On the other hand, in complete linkage the distance between the farthest points are taken as the intra cluster distance

Comment: Welcome to SO; please see the NOTE in the [`machine-learning` tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory.

Comment: you could save this with language-specific code example.